# how to find out the value in the EAV table is filled or not

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem here, I use a database with the EAV (Entity Artibute Value) model, here I get data by way of, `where user_id = $ id -> get ()`, and on the blade I want to create a condition if only one the data in $ user has a value in the description column so he will bring up a button from the description that has the contents
this my sampel table

```
_______________________________________
|id|user_id|name    |description       |
|1| 2      |micahel |                  |
|2| 2      |micahel |                  |
|3| 2      |micahel |                  |
|4| 2      |micahel |www.google.com    |
|5| 3      |jackson |                  |
|6| 3      |jackson |                  |
|7| 3      |jackson |                  |


$table = DB::table(description)->where(user_id,$id)->get();
```

so my expectation is, if there is only one data that I take with where has a value in the value column, it will bring up the href button,
i try with

```
@if($table->description!=0)
<a href="{{$table->description}}">go to description</a>
@else
This user has no description
@endif
```

i try that but it's doesn't work

```
Property [description] does not exist on this collection instance
```

Comment: Have you tried the `whereNotNull` method?

Comment: Never sir, I will try now

Answer (score 1):

If you would try and "die and dump" (`dd($table)`) the contents of `$table` you will see that it's a collection actually.

If you only expect a single row in return of your query you can use `first()` instead of `get()`. `get()` will always return a [`Collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-collections) even if there is only 1 or 0 results.

---

I want to add that `@if($table->description!=0)` would not work either way since it will never be `not 0` since an empty result would be either `null` or an empty string. To test if `description` contains an value I would use `empty()` like: `@if(!empty($row->description))`.

Comment: I deliberately use get, because I want if between 4 data (user_id = 2) there is a description then displays the download button,